# I need a script to check the Color Setting

Tags: javascript, jsx, photoshop, photoshop-script

I need a script to check Color Setting and change to another one or use it before I work with my pictures

[image: Color Settings]

I found a listener script can load a CSF file but don't know how to check the Color Settings.

```
var idcolorSettings = stringIDToTypeID( "colorSettings" );

if (idcolorSettings == "Untitled1.CSF") //something wrong here
{
var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
    var desc38 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
       var ref13 = new ActionReference();
        var idPrpr = charIDToTypeID( "Prpr" );
        var idcolorSettings = stringIDToTypeID( "colorSettings" );
        ref13.putProperty( idPrpr, idcolorSettings );
        var idcapp = charIDToTypeID( "capp" );
        var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
        var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
        ref13.putEnumerated( idcapp, idOrdn, idTrgt );
    desc38.putReference( idnull, ref13 );
    var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
        var desc39 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
        desc39.putPath( idUsng, new File( ".../AppData/Roaming/Adobe/Color/Settings/Untitled2.CSF" ) );
    var idcolorSettings = stringIDToTypeID( "colorSettings" );
    desc38.putObject( idT, idcolorSettings, desc39 );
executeAction( idsetd, desc38, DialogModes.NO );
load
}
else {
//will change another CSF file
}
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: You can get the name of the current colour settings with `alert(app.colorSettings);`

Comment: @GhoulFool but it just show me which Color Setting is running. I want photoshop auto change with specify file name. Because I have 2 types of photo need to work on 2 types of Color Setting.

Like below: 

if (app.activeDocument.name.indexOf ("_A_") != -1) 
{
// load Untitled1.CSF
}
else (if (app.activeDocument.name.indexOf ("_2_") != -1)
{
// load Untitled2.CSF
}

Comment: Changed on the name of the file you're working on. That's the important bit. Got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the risk that I've mis-understood your question here goes:
Change the USERNAME or the absolute path to fit your needs. Apply your script to the  Script Events Manager to Open a New Document - so you won't have to run the script each time you open a script.

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR; // OFF

load_colour_settings();

// Set Display Dialogs back to normal
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // NORMAL


function load_colour_settings()
{
  
  if (app.activeDocument.name.indexOf ("A") != -1)
  { 
    // load Untitled1.CSF 
    var colourFile = "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Roaming\\Adobe\\Color\\Settings\\Untitled1.CSF";
  }
  else if (app.activeDocument.name.indexOf ("2") != -1) 
  { 
  // load Untitled2.CSF 
    var colourFile = "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Roaming\\Adobe\\Color\\Settings\\Untitled2.CSF";
  }
  // None of the above? Don't do anything
  else return;

  // alert(colourFile);
  var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
  var desc38 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref13 = new ActionReference();
  var idPrpr = charIDToTypeID( "Prpr" );
  var idcolorSettings = stringIDToTypeID( "colorSettings" );
  ref13.putProperty( idPrpr, idcolorSettings );
  var idcapp = charIDToTypeID( "capp" );
  var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
  var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
  ref13.putEnumerated( idcapp, idOrdn, idTrgt );
  desc38.putReference( idnull, ref13 );
  var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
  var desc39 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
  desc39.putPath( idUsng, new File( colourFile ) );
  var idcolorSettings = stringIDToTypeID( "colorSettings" );
  desc38.putObject( idT, idcolorSettings, desc39 );
  executeAction( idsetd, desc38, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

Comment: It worked great. thanks bro